# Issue with ActionCable handling an audio stream from Twilio, "Received unrecognized command in..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, rubygems, twilio, streaming

I recently started a project that requires speech recognition in realtime, using google "speech to text" and Twilio's API (virtual phone service) .

The general overview is, during a virtual phone call using Twilio the audio stream of the call is forked and directed at a websocket url handled in my rails app, which should receive this audio stream in realtime and eventually send it to a speech to text API to receive a transcript and send that to somebody's browser in order to display it.

So it's almost like displaying captions during a phone call, in which the caller is seeing whatever is being spoken as text in real-time.

I couldn't find any active documentation on how to achieve this with rails...But there's seems to be a lot of easy ways to do it in other languages.

Just as an example, here's literally a 2 minute read tutorial with everything I needed, but done using node js. I'll put the link because I think it will clarify more or less what I want to do, in case that I didn't explain myself well enough:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text

In case you wanna skip the thing and just go to the meat of it, here's a screenshot of the thing I need to replicate in rails:

[Node JS Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1bpu.png)

So without much guidance I tried to implement this myself and just pointed the stream to my websocket url, similar to how is done in the screenshot. I was able to get pass the initial handshake (using ngrok to tunnel my localhost btw), but I struggled with being able to handle the received data from the audio stream. I couldn't find a way to access this raw data stream, and because of that, I couldn't even do simple things like deciding what to do depending on the "event type" key. It seems action_cable requires data streamed in a very specific format or it breaks, because after setting all up I kept getting the same error the moment the websocket streaming started.

It printed the following to the console for as long as the call lasted.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAYrD.png)

This went on for as long as I had the call going, so it's clearly the audio stream data encoded somehow, which is exactly what I needed. Except this was being printed as part of an error log.

I was able to track down the exact code where this error was being raised, inside the action_cable source code. As you can see in the screenshot, there's a case statement thats raising the error, because the received data doesn't match any of the predefined scenarios. At that point data should be a string, but instead of that i'm getting this big json I just posted.

[ActionCable Source Code Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWdlY.png)

Is it possible to do what I described using rails (I kind of refuse to accept it's not possible, there must be a way!). If so, can somebody point me in the correct direction, help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Forgot to mention I found this example app on Twilio's official demos page. It does exactly what I need using rails, but it uses a gem called Tubesock, which is no longer being maintained as rails now moved to using ActionCable instead.

Here's a quick snippet of the relevant code:

```
    class ChatController < ApplicationController
      include Tubesock::Hijack

      def chat
        hijack do |tubesock|
          tubesock.onopen do
            tubesock.send_data "Hello, friend"
          end

          tubesock.onmessage do |data|
            tubesock.send_data "You said: #{data}"
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

As you can see, it's extremely simple, it acts as a middlewhere and allows me to modify data before passing it on, it gives me the chance to do different things when certain events trigger, like "opening a connection" or "receiving a message" in the websocket.

So, this is definitely possible, the question is, how come ActionCable does not support something like this?

Is there any other library still maintained that would something similar?

I'll leave the relevant link in case you want to take a look:

https://github.com/twilio/media-streams/tree/dc8fbed6f32c452a7baa6c35b3439e8401b19821/ruby/rails-controller

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. TubeSock would hijack the IO socket and use raw WebSockets. In contrast, ActionCable uses the ActionCable sub-protocol (which is basically a specific JSON format)... you can either "fix" the incoming messages to fit the JSON format required by ActionCable (if at all possible), or use raw WebSockets (I authored [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) for that, but there are other options)

Comment: Hi @Myst!, thanks for replying. I do not control the original format of the data so I don't have a way to modify it, which would have been an ideal solution. I checked your gem, but from what I read, we would have to replace our puma for iodine, and I don't want to go that deep into changing things. Is there any raw websocket library you might recommend for this scenario? something more of a standalone functionality? What would be the correct term for what im trying to find (so I can search it properly myself).

Comment: It's  true, iodine will require you to switch away from Puma (which may be good or bad, depending on how you set things up). Maybe look into [Faye WebSockets](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) and see if that could work as middleware for your needs.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. Paste the code as text in a code block instead. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you should not ask for "any other library", ask if there is a way instead. Curators tend to see it and assume you're asking us to find a library for you.