# Error google.cloud.speech.v1.Speech.StreamingRecognize

Tags: ruby, twilio, streaming, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to stream audio from Twilio using( twiml) and then transcribe it with google speech to text.  Audio streaming is working and I am sending samples to google but I always have this error: `google.cloud.speech.v1.Speech.StreamingRecognize`

This error is only present on cloud console and I do not have any response from gem. So, I don't receive transcriptions and no error. Maybe, there is the way to catch an error in gem. I wasn't able to find it in API reference.

Please, help

Error:
[image]

Code:

```rb
module Twilio
  class CallsController < ApplicationController
    include Tubesock::Hijack

    def stream
      puts "params = #{params.inspect}"

      speech = ::Google::Cloud::Speech.speech version: :v1p1beta1 do |config|
        config.credentials = Settings.google.credentials_path
      end

      @input_stream = Gapic::StreamInput.new
      speech.streaming_recognize @input_stream do |response, opp|
        pp 'transcription'
        pp response
        pp opp
      end
      @input_stream.push streaming_config: {
        config: {
          encoding:                 'MULAW',
          sample_rate_hertz:        8000,
          language_code:            "en-US"
        }
      }


      hijack do |tubesock|
        tubesock.onopen do
          p 'open -s'
        end

        tubesock.onmessage do |data|
          parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)

          if parsed_data['event'] == 'connected'
            p 'connected'
          elsif parsed_data['event'] == 'media'
            payload = Base64.decode64(parsed_data.dig('media', 'payload'))
            pp "Payload: #{payload}"
            @input_stream << {audio_content: payload}if payload.present?
          end
        end

        tubesock.onclose do
          p 'close'
        end

        tubesock.onerror do |e|
          p e
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Log:

```
app_1     | [86b5-5-59-117-90] [c2b5ebf3-ca9d-4c7c-9fbe-92d248841703] Started GET "/twilio/calls/stream" for 3.235.111.253 at 2022-09-07 07:06:37 +0000
app_1     | [86b5-5-59-117-90] [c2b5ebf3-ca9d-4c7c-9fbe-92d248841703] Processing by Twilio::CallsController#stream as HTML
app_1     | params = #<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"twilio/calls", "action"=>"stream"} permitted: false>
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:37.678675 #1] DEBUG -- : calling speech.googleapis.com:/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.Speech/StreamingRecognize
app_1     | "transcription"
app_1     | #<Enumerator: ...>
app_1     | #<GRPC::ActiveCall::Operation:0x0000ffffa1b9ed48
app_1     |  @wrapped=
app_1     |   D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.255889 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: starting
app_1     | #<GRPC::ActiveCall:0x0000ffffa1b9f108
app_1     |    @call=
app_1     |     #<GRPC::Core::Call:0x0000ffffa1b9f180>,
app_1     |    @call_finished=
app_1     |     false,
app_1     |    @call_finished_mu=
app_1     |     #<Thread::Mutex:0x0000ffffa1b9eff0>,
app_1     |    @client_call_executed=
app_1     |     true,
app_1     |    @client_call_executed_mu=
app_1     |     #<Thread::Mutex:0x0000ffffa1b9efa0>,
app_1     |    @deadline=
app_1     |     2022-09-07 08:29:57.678494918 +0000,
app_1     |    @input_stream_done=
app_1     |     false,
app_1     |    @marshal=
app_1     |     #<Proc:0x0000ffffa1b0b6d8 /usr/local/bundle/gems/grpc-1.48.0/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/rpc_desc.rb:35>,
app_1     |    @Metadata_received=
app_1     |     false,
app_1     |    @Metadata_sent=
app_1     |     true,
app_1     |    @Metadata_to_send=
app_1     |     {:"x-goog-api-client"=>
app_1     |       "gl-ruby/3.1.2 gax/0.11.1 gapic/0.13.0 grpc/1.48.0"},
app_1     |    @op_notifier=
app_1     |     #<GRPC::Notifier:0x0000ffffa1b9ee38
app_1     |      @cvar=
app_1     |       #<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x0000ffffa1b9ed98>,
app_1     |      @mutex=
app_1     |       #<Thread::Mutex:0x0000ffffa1b9ede8>,
app_1     |      @notified=
app_1     |       false,
app_1     |      @payload=
app_1     |       nil>,
app_1     |    @output_stream_done=
app_1     |     false,
app_1     |    @peer=
app_1     |     "speech.googleapis.com",
app_1     |    @send_initial_md_mutex=
app_1     |     #<Thread::Mutex:0x0000ffffa1b9f068>,
app_1     |    @unmarshal=
app_1     |     #<Proc:0x0000ffffa1b0b660 /usr/local/bundle/gems/grpc-1.48.0/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/rpc_desc.rb:47>>>
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.328125 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 0
app_1     | [86b5-5-59-117-90] [c2b5ebf3-ca9d-4c7c-9fbe-92d248841703] Completed -1  in 1260ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3898)
app_1     |
app_1     |
app_1     | "open -s"
app_1     | "connected"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.463612 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 1
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.464068 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 2
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.581567 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 3
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.582112 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 4
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.582256 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 5
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.585495 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 6
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.586073 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 7
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.589631 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 8
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.592105 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 9
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.592238 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 10
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.593880 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 11
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFE~~~\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF~\xFF\xFE\xFF~~~\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF~~\xFE\xFE|~{\xFC\xFB}~}\xFD\xFE~}~\xFE\xFE~}\xFF\xFC\xFE~}\xFF\xFD\xFD}~\xFE\xFE\xFD~\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFF~\xFE\xFE\xFC\xFE}~\xFF\xFC\xFE~}}\xFC\xFE\xFE~\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFD~~~\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF~~\xFC\xFE~}}\xFD\xFE~~}\xFF\xFE\xFF~}~\xFE~\xFF\xFE\xFE}~\xFE~\xFE||\xFD\xFE\xFF}~~\xFC\xFE}\xFF~\xFF\xFE\xFF}\xFD\xFD~}\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF}\xFF\xFD\xFE"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF}\xFF\xFB\xFE|~\xFF\xFE\xFC}}\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFD~~~\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE~}\xFE\xFD\xFD~}\xFF\xFD\xFC~\xFF~\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE~\xFE~~\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFF~\xFE~\xFF\xFD\xFF~~~\xFE\xFC\xFF\xFF}}\xFE\xFC~~|\xFE\xFC\xFE~|~\xFE\xFC}{\xFE\xFE\xFC~{}\xFD\xFD~}|\xFE\xFC~\xFF}}\xFD~\xFF\xFE~\xFF~~}\xFD\xFE\xFF}}\xFE\xFF\xFE~}\xFD\xFE~\xFE~\xFF\xFC\xFD|}\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFD}~\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFF\xFF~\xFE~\xFE\xFD\xFE~}~\xFD\xFB\xFF|~~\xFC\xFC}}}\xFE\xFD\xFD"
app_1     | "Payload: }|\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE}~\xFD}|\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFD}}\xFD}~~\xFE\xFE\xFE}|\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFE~~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFD\xFE\xFF~~\xFF\xFD\xFD\xFE}~\xFD\xFC~}}\xFD\xFC\xFE~|\xFC\xFD\xFE~}\xFF\xFC\xFD~|}\xFC\xFE\xFD}|\xFE\xFC~\xFF\xFF~\xFF\xFF}\xFE\xFD~}~\xFE\xFD\xFE|}\xFE\xFD\xFD~{\xFF\xFD\xFD\xFE}|\xFD\xFD\xFE~}\xFE\xFC\xFE\xFE~}\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFF~~\xFE\xFE\xFE}\xFF\xFE\xFC\xFD}}\xFE\xFC\xFD~|~\xFC\xFD~}\xFE\xFD\xFD~}~\xFD\xFE~\xFF\xFF\xFE~~~\xFD\xFD}}\xFE\xFD"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.598419 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 12
app_1     | "Payload: \xFD~|~\xFD\xFD\xFD}|\xFE\xFE\xFE~~~~\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF~}\xFE\xFD\xFF~}\xFE\xFC\xFE}}~\xFC\xFC~|~\xFD\xFE\xFE~}\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE~}\xFE~\xFE\xFE}~\xFD\xFF~\xFE~\xFF\xFE\xFF~\xFE\xFF\xFE~~~\xFD\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\xFD\xFE|}\xFD\xFB\xFF~{\xFD\xFB~}}\xFF\xF9\xFF||\xFE\xFC\xFC|{\xFD\xFB\xFD|\xFE{\xFB\xFD~~\xFF\xFD~\xFF\xFE}\xFE}\xFE\xFE~\xFE|\xFC\xFE\xFE{~\xFC\xFD}z~\xFB\xFC}||\xFB\xFC~}|\xFB\xFD}\xFF|\xFD\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF~~\xFE\xFE\xFD~~"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFE\xFE\xFD}}\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF~\xFD\xFF\xFE\xFE~~~\xFF\xFC\xFE\xFF{\xFE\xFA|\xFE{\xFD\xFD\xFF\xFF|\xFD\xFE~~~\xFD\xFE~}}\xFC\xFE}~\xFF\xFE\xFE~~~~\xFE\xFF\xFD\xFF{}\xFD\xFD\xFF}|\xFD\xFB\xFF}|\xFD\xFC\xFE~\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFD\xFE\xFF~}\xFD\xFC\xFF|\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFD~~~\xFD\xFE\xFF~}\xFE\xFC~}~\xFF~\xFE\xFE~~}}\xFD\xFE\xFE~~~\xFE\xFE\xFF|~\xFD\xFC\xFE|}\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFE|~\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFD\xFF~\xFF\xFE~\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE~\xFF\xFB\xFE}~\xFB\xFC\xFE}"
app_1     | "Payload: ~\xFB\xFC\xFF\xFF}\xFC\xFC\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFF\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFF\xFF\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFE~\xFE\xFB\xFB\xFE|~\xFB\xFC\xFD~}\xFB\xFB\xFE~\xFD\xFF\xFD~\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFE}\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF~\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFF}~\xFF\xFF\xFF~}}\xFE~\xFE{|~\xFF}~~|~|~}}z}~~{{|}{|z|}z{|||zy|z{z{{{y|zy{|yzz{~zwx}||wy~~|xx\xFF~|zx}\xFC}x|}\xFF~zz\xFE\xFE{|{~\xFE"
app_1     | "Payload: }||\xFE}~|~\xFE\xFF|z\xFF\xFE\xFD|{~\xFD\xFF}|}\xFD~\xFF|\xFD}~\xFD~\xFF}\xFE\xFD\xFC\xFE}}\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFF~\xFE\xFB\xFC\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFA\xFC\xFE\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFE\xFA\xF9\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFB\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFA\xFA\xFB\xFB\xFB\xFC\xFA\xFB\xFB\xFA\xFA\xFC\xFA\xFA\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFA\xF9\xFA\xFC\xFB\xFB\xF9\xFA\xFC\xFC\xFA\xF9\xFA\xFA\xFB\xF9\xFB\xFA\xFA\xFA\xF9\xF9\xFC\xFB\xF8\xFA\xFA\xFB\xFB\xFA\xF7\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFA\xF9\xFA\xFC\xFE\xFA\xF8\xFC\xFE\xFD\xFB\xFA\xFC~\xFE\xFB\xFC\xFF}\xFE\xFC\xFC}|~\xFE\xFD}{}}\xFE}{{"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.598857 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 13
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.600643 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 14
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.600726 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 15
app_1     | "Payload: |~}{{||||{{|||{{{{|}{|||}{|}~{||~~{{}\xFD~}z}\xFE\xFE||}\xFE\xFD}{}\xFD\xFD~|}\xFF\xFD\xFF}}\xFF\xFE\xFF~~\xFE\xFF~~~\xFF\xFE~\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE~\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFD~\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFB\xFD\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFC\xFD\xFD~\xFF\xFD\xFE\xFE~\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFF~~\xFE\xFF~}}\xFF|}}}~|||}}|{|{~{{}y\xFE{||}}|~{}~}~~|~\xFF\xFE~\xFE~\xFD"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFC\xFE\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF~~~~~~}}}}}}}||||||||||{{|{||{{||{|{|||||||||||||||||||}|||"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.602258 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 16
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.602551 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 17
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.603303 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 18
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.603703 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 19
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.604072 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 20
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.604155 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 21
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.604299 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 22
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.605005 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 23
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.605063 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 24
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.606119 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 25
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.606228 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 26
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.606341 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 27
app_1     | "Payload: }~}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF~~~~~~~~}}}}}}}|}|}}|}|}||||}|}||||||"
app_1     | "Payload: }|}||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~}~}~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFE~\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.681226 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 28
app_1     | "Payload: \xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF\xFF~\xFF~~~~~~~~~~~}~~~~~~~}~}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}|}|}}}|}|}|}|}}|}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}"
app_1     | "Payload: }}}}}}}}}~}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFF~\xFE~\xFF~~~\xFE~\xFF~~\xFF\xFF~~~~\xFF\xFF\xFF~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF~~~~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFC"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.682072 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 29
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.683420 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 30
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.683532 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 31
app_1     | "Payload: \xFD\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF~\xFE\xFF\xFF~~\xFF~\xFF~~\xFF~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF~~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~~~\xFF~~~~~\xFF\xFF~\xFF~\xFF\xFF~~~~\xFF~\xFF"
app_1     | "Payload: ~~\xFF~~~\xFF~\xFF~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF}\xFF~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF~~~~~~~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~~~~\xFF~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF~\xFF~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\xFF~\xFF~\xFF~~~~\xFF\xFF~\xFF~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF~\xFF~\xFE~\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.684466 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 32
app_1     | "Payload: \xFF\xFE\xFD\xFE\xFE\xFB\xFE\xFC\xFD\xFD\xFC\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFA\xFB\xFB\xFA\xFC\xFB\xF9\xFD\xFA\xFB\xFB\xFB\xFA\xFC\xFC\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFB\xFA\xFC\xFA\xFB\xFD\xFC\xF9\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFB\xFB\xFB\xFB\xFE\xFB\xFB\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFC\xFB\xFA\xFE\xFD\xFC\xFB\xFB\xFD\xFE\xFC\xFC\xFA\xFE\xFF\xFC\xFB\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFA\xFF\xFE\xFF\xFC\xFC\xFE}~\xFD~\xFD{|\xFE\xFD|||\xFF~\xFD{y\xFD\xFF}|{~\xFD{|}~\xFCzy|\xFE~|y}\xFF{~}|\xFD\xFFz~~\xFD\xFE\xFE}~\xFB\xFE\xFD~\xFF\xFD\xFC}\xFF\xFE\xFD\xFF\xFF\xFE~\xFD\xFD\xFD~\xFC~\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFB"
app_1     | "Payload: \xFD\xFD\xFC\xFD\xFC\xFA\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFD\xFE\xFF\xFC\xFF\xFF\xFE\xFF}\xFE~~\xFD{}\xFF{\xFF}{}}}|||z|z{xzzyyyxzxyywzuyxxyxyxyzxxzwzyvzwzxxywzyxy{wzzzzz|z|{|{z||z}z|}y~z|}z~z||{||||}~}|~{|\xFE{||{~||}{~|}}z}||}|}|~}}~}|~}}}|~}|~"D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.685077 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 33
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.686361 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 34
app_1     |
app_1     | "Payload: |}~{~|{|{}}{~}}}\xFF|~}|\xFF||}~|||||}{}}}~\xFD\xFE\xFD\xFB\xFB\xFA\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFA\xFE\xFE\xFC~|~z~~v\xFC\xFCz\xFA\xFF\xFD\xFAz}\xFDz{\xFFw|~{\xFF\xFC\xFE\xFC\xF8\xF8\xFD\xFB\xF5\xFA~\xFE\xF8wy\xFFqzvoyxnsyswyxy\xF8}u\xFE\xFClrzgnmkw|s\xF3\xEC\xEA\xDC\xDD\xDB\xD4\xD9\xD7\xD4\xDB\xDE\xE3\xFAtf\\\\SPTUQU\\]fch\xF7vlvon\xFDoo\xFCz\xE5"
app_1     | "Payload: \xE8\xDC\xD3\xDA\xD1\xD1\xD6\xD4\xD8\xF3\xFEqWQTMMMMY\\j\xFD\xE0\xD6\xD2\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD0\xD2\xE0\xF5\xDEgU\\YfOSxbm\xFD\xF0\xE2\xDF\xE0\xDF\xDD\xDE\xDE\xE5\xE3\xEE\xE7\xFDrfh\\XWZ[]j]\xC5\xCF\xE0\xB7\xB9\xC5\xB2\xBC\xBF\xB9\xE5^Z<0/+()4*6^_\xC5\xB6\xB6\xAB\xA9\xB2\xAE\xB0\xBF\xDEo@<4.476BX\xDC\xC7\xBE\xB6\xB0\xB3\xAE\xB5\xBB\xBB\xC4\xC8\xD5\xE0maRRCF=<3:/2-?N.\xE7\xCD\xCF\xBE\xB8\xBE\xA9\xB9\xC8\xB4\xC1zQR>C4"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.687333 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 35
app_1     | "Payload: 6JE>j\xD3\xCB\xC1\xC3\xB8\xB6\xBA\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBF\xC5\xCC\xCB\xDB\xDF\xFD\xDCTRLJ;=505**/\xE7)@\xC1\xE3\xBF\xB7\xBC\xAC\xA8\xFD\xB0\xB4\xDAM\\D?<.DN<D\xCC\xCE\xC6\xC3\xBE\xB2\xB9\xBB\xB6\xB7\xBD\xBE\xC0\xC4\xC9\xD4\xDC\xCA~_]UCE7;5*/+!+\xC6!6\xB6T\xBD\xAF\xC1\xAB\xA0\xF4\xB3\xAC\xC8I|N9G-5\\?5\xD8\xC4\xD9\xBF\xBD\xB3\xB0\xAC\xBC\xB3\xA8\xBC\xBE\xB8\xBD\xD2\xCB^cd?6><-13(.-\x1F0>80z\xBD\xC3\xB6\xB5\xAE\xA9\xAC\xCA\xB1"
app_1     | D, [2022-09-07T07:06:38.688055 #1] DEBUG -- : bidi-write-loop: 36
```

Comment: You have a confusing collection of libraries and versions involved here. Tubesock is deprecated in favour of ActionCable and Gapic is described as a preview. You're choosing the "v1p1beta1" version of Google Cloud Speech when "v1" is available.  Might this all work together better with the most up to date versions of the dependencies/APIs?

Comment: @philnash I am using Tubesock because ActionCable has it's own sub-protocol that is not supported by Twilio([another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493033/issue-with-actioncable-handling-an-audio-stream-from-twilio-received-unrecogni#comment112277885_63493033)). I have done most of the testing with google cloud api V1. The same result. So, I think it is not a problem

Comment: Is there any more detail on the error you are seeing in the console?

Comment: @philnash No. That is a primary problem.

Comment: You might need to bring this up with Google Cloud to see what more you can learn. I can’t see anything that’s obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: @AndriyPokynboroda were there any resolution to this? I've been troubleshooting for 5 days and still cant get it works.